# Чем отличается виртуальная память от набора мест в памяти

Tags: javascript, память, ecmascript-6

Вопрос может показаться неправильным. Но я поясню в чем дело.
Читая спецификацию ecma262 наткнулся на тип данных Data Blocks. Там есть неплохое описание что это такое. Понятное дело что этот тип используется как абстракция на уровне самой спецификации. Но я хотел бы знать следующее(цитирую):

> A Shared Data Block has an identity (for the purposes of equality testing Shared Data Block values) that is address-free : it is tied not to the virtual addresses the block is mapped to in any process, but to the set of locations in memory that the block represents.

Как можно заметить тут делается акцент на *виртуальной памяти* и *набором мест в памяти*. Только вот проблема, а разница какая-то есть? Если кто знает поделитесь информацией